# Can I extend a tourist visa inside Vietnam?

Tags: tourist-visas, vietnam, visa-extensions

I can get a tourist visa with the span of one month upmost to Vietnam (as of February 2020 only USA citizens can get more than that and I don't hold a USA citizenship).

If I arrive to Vietnam with a one month tourist visa, should I be able to extend it to some more time, say, one more month to six months, inside Vietnam and if so, please detail from experience on how should this be done?

In appreciation of your experience, time and help !

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.myvietnamvisa.com/vietnam-visa-extension.html it looks like you can extend for a further 90 days up to a total 6 month stay.

You need to complete an application form and take it to the Immigration office. There does seem to be some debate on that site as to whether you can do this yourself or must go through a local agency.

Comment: Hello, I had a mistake in the question (please revise); I now offer bounty I will most likely give to you ; I must leave my home now but I should do some research myself later today,

Comment: I re read there ; if I understood correctly, a receiver of 1 month visa such as myself could extend only 3 times up two 4 months (1 + `1+1+1` months).